# Duplicate prints with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I m trying to create a animation with ggplot and gganimate combination but i m getting prints left on my graph.The dots are not moving properly. I appreciate any help.

My code

```
ggplot(newfile, aes(Date,  TotalReturn, color = Investor)) +
  geom_line(aes(size = 3)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = 6,alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(TotalReturn,"%")),
            hjust= -0.5, vjust=0,size = 6)+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Investor)) +
  labs(title = 'Total Return, Quarter: {frame_along}') +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(face="bold.italic", 
                                size="12", color="brown"), 
        legend.position="none") + 
  transition_reveal(along =Date) +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(qp, duration = 100)
```

[image: gif]

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(newfile)` in your question for reproducibility.

Comment: Z.Lin sorry this issue is fixed when i rerun the code.